# SharePoint Online Friendly URL's

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-management

We have a single tenancy O365.  It is at http://myparentcompany.sharepoint.com

We have a number of business units within our parent company.

In order to communicate to our internal users a "friendly" URL that reflects the information architecture of our content we would like to be able to provide a structure that is easy to understand.

Is it possible in SharePoint online to provide a url similar to the following?:

http://myparentcompany.sharepoint.com/businessunit1/somebusite
http://myparentcompany.sharepoint.com/businessunit2/somebusite
etc.

alternatively is it better to do something like?

http://businessunit1.myparentcompany.com/sites/somesite
etc.

If so how are any of the above solutions implemented for SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Online is always `tenant.sharepoint.com`. You can then branch off site collections as `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/businessunit` or `tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/businessunit` or branch them all off the root as subsites `tenant.sharepoint.com/businessunit`. Those are your only options for any sort of information architecture.